# enable https certificate AWS beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lets-encrypt

I deployed my node.js application to AWS beanstalk.

Now, I try to enable https certificate for my  application. However, most tutorials suggest people to use AWS load balance.

Is it possible to enable https without using AWS load balance? If so, could I use the certificate generated by Let's encrypt?

Answer (score 0):

> If so, could I use the certificate generated by Let's encrypt?

Yes you could. This process requires deploying your certificates on the instance with the help of nginx. AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html) explain how to do it. But the instructions are for EB platforms based Amazon Linux 1 (AL1). If you are using AM2, you would have to adjust the instructions to this platform.